# Knocked out by nested editor 3 or more levels deep

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mvc

When trying to extend the live example for a nested editor provided on the KO site ( http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/gZC5k/ ) to change the layout and add deeper levels, I've not been able to tackle two issues.

although I was able to get to this stage http://jsfiddle.net/gZC5k/955/

I got stuck with somewhere in building the correct hierarchy in the model,

```
    var ContactsModel = function (contacts) {
var self = this;
self.contacts = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contacts, function (contact) {
    return {
        firstName: contact.firstName,
        lastName: contact.lastName,
        phones: ko.observableArray(contact.phones),
        addresses: ko.observableArray(contact.addresses)
    };
}));
```

The two issues are:

- not being able to add a new  "Call" to a "Phone" that is loaded in the initial dataset (When I create a new Phone, I can add "Calls")
- not being able to delete "Calls".

  ```
  self.removeCall = function (call) {
  $.each(self.phones(), function () {
      this.calls.remove(call)
  })
  ```

  };

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I have fixed your model.Replace this code in fiddle, and then check**

**It works perfect**

```
self.contacts = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contacts, function (contact) {
    return {
        firstName: contact.firstName,
        lastName: contact.lastName,
        addresses: ko.observableArray(contact.addresses),
        phones: ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(contact.phones, function (phone) {
            return{
                type: phone.type,
                number: phone.number,
                calls: ko.observableArray(phone.calls)
            };
        }))
    };
}));
```

Comment: Thanks @Boss !  Overlooked that one completely. further optimized by transferring the Remove functions to the html, so that there's no need to loop to traverse the entire object tree. Guess that will be faster when having lots of data.

Answer (score 1):

Since remove() function expecting observable array, make calls as observableArray

then change **removeCall** method as below

```
self.removeCall = function (call) {
      alert(ko.toJSON(call));
     $.each(self.contacts(), function () {
        $.each(this.phones(), function () {
            alert(ko.toJSON(this));
        this.calls.remove(call)
    })
    })
};
```

For **addCall** method follow the same structure of **removeCall**

Comment: thanks @Boss. Still struggling though with making calls an observable array  (tried this : http://jsfiddle.net/gZC5k/977/ ), but unsuccessful. So your correct  solution (as far as I can see) still doesn't have the effect I was hoping for. It always tries to remove the call from the first number). But as I said, the error is in the model, not your solution.

Comment: I have fixed the syntax error in your view model added as another answer.Check it